# how to create a array of values from dictionary having specific key?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Input

```
dict = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},{a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}, {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9} ]
```

Output to array having only values of key 'a' in typescript

```
array = [ 1, 4, 7 ]
```

Comment: `dict.map(({a}) => a)`

Comment: You will find a description of all array prototype methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use the [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
> dict = [ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 }, { a: 7, b: 8, c: 9 } ]
[ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 4, b: 5, c: 6 }, { a: 7, b: 8, c: 9 } ]
> dict.map(({a}) => a)
[ 1, 4, 7 ]
>
```